# maven package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist for KassandraMRHelper

Tags: java, maven

So I am trying to install a library to process my Cassandra files.

```
https://github.com/Knewton/KassandraMRHelper
```

I get an error when I try

```
mvn package
```

I tried

```
mvn compile
```

but got the following error

```
[Error] KassandraMRHelper/src/main/java/com/knewton/thrift/StudentEventData.java:[9,31] error: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
```

[here](https://github.com/Knewton/KassandraMRHelper/blob/master/pom.xml) is the pom.xml file. I am new to maven so any help will be amazing!

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by updating the version number of thrift library to 0.9.0!
Sometimes the wildest experiments end up working for you